# How To Add Item To ng-repeat list and stop list item being changed by databinding

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I need to build an ng-repeat list from values typed and submitted using html inputs. It works, I can return the item from the input using ng-repeat, but when editing the input for the next item, the input value is still bound to the value in the ng-repeat, and then changes that value instead of adding a completely new one. I'm sure I'm missing something simple, but stuck at the moment.

How do I add new items that are not binded to the input on each ng-click?

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
Hello, {{name}}!
<br/>
<input ng-model='newitem1' />
<input ng-model='newitem2' />
<input ng-model='newitem3' />
<button ng-click='add()'>Add</button>

<br/>
<b>Items Added Below</b>
<div select-last ng-repeat='item in items'>
    <div ng-model='item' id='item-{{$index}}' class='input-{{$index}}'>{{newitem1}} {{newitem2}} {{newitem3}}</div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.directive('selectLast', function () {
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {

        if (scope.$last=== true) {
            console.log("the last element is here");
        }
    }
});
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'Please try entering something and click Add button';
    $scope.items = [];
    $scope.newitem1 = '';
    $scope.newitem2 = '';
    $scope.newitem3 = '';

    $scope.add = function(){
      $scope.items.push($scope.newitem1,$scope.newitem2,$scope.newitem3);  
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could clone the item using `angular.copy()` so it is a copy of the data, however not a direct reference to it.

This will allow you to continually add new items.

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'Please try entering something and click Add button';
    $scope.items = [];
    $scope.newitem1 = '';
    $scope.newitem2 = '';
    $scope.newitem3 = '';

    $scope.add = function(){
      var item1 = angular.copy($scope.newitem1),
          item2 = angular.copy($scope.newitem2),
          item3 = angular.copy($scope.newitem3);
      $scope.items.push(item1, item2, item3);  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I realized that I was using the input model for my expression.

```
{{newitem1}}
```

Instead of

```
{{item.newitem1}}
```

Fixed